# Excel Macro Explanation

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

What does this macro code does ?

```
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
    FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(14, 1), Array(15, 1), Array(17, 1), _
    Array(26, 1), Array(35, 1), Array(39, 1), Array(43, 1), Array(53, 1), Array(62, 1), Array( _
    70, 1), Array(85, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```

I get it it's destination is A1, and data somehow is fixed column width. I have been given this macro, but I simply can't understand what it does ?

It would be great if you could direct me to the right direction.

Comment: Have a read on [MSDN's Range.TextToColumns Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb178160(v=office.12).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you record a macro using the `TextToColumns` feature, and use the `Fixed Width` option, you will obtain such code. The Array values specify at which character-width each column is created.

Comment: so this means macro was recorded via selection made and each array represent length(char) or width ? so Array(3,1) is 3 char long, and second column from the code mentioned ?

Comment: That sounds right. As I say, the quickest way to convince yourself would be to record a quick macro.

Comment: Generally, though not necessarily, anytime you see a procedure utilizing the Selection object, it's a recorded procedure. The selection object is very easily avoided and in practical use, it's only really useful in certain object events, but almost never in sub procedures.